# PHP show 2 days data from current date

Tags: php, date

I want to show data from 2 days ago to current date, but I can't seem to figure it out. How can I do this?

thanks

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the filling your are trying to fetch data from DB?

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `date_field` BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Thanks @Glavic, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the date two days ago and today.

```
$two_days_ago = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 days'));
$today = date('Y-m-d');
```

This is the basic structure of the query that will get the rows that are on or between those dates. If your date column is indexed this query will utilize it for performance.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE datecol >= '{$two_days_ago}' AND datecol <= '{$today}'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 days'));
```

Comment: That will get them the date two days ago but I think the question is much broader. They want to get the data from a db and I suspect they want that code, too.

Comment: yes @John i am agree with you

Comment: With due respect, @John Conde, I don't see it as the question being too broad - maybe because of lack of knowledge in PHP and/or DB. I just wanted the data from the DB from 2 days ago to today's date as stated in the question. I marked Glavic's response as the answer since it's exactly what I wanted. Could you please elaborate how the question was broad so that I can make sure this doesn't happen in the future.

Comment: @user1828605 I didnt mean the question was too broad. I  meant what you aksed was broader in scope than this answer accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new DateTime();

$date->modify("-2 day");

echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```